# Specify which lines that should be executed in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

I have about 400 lines of code in a .m-file. This file is executed A LOT of times so it the biggest time consumer in the program. Sometimes when I execute the program I only need to run about 50 of the 400 lines (which of the 50 lines will be determined at the beginning of execution). I wish to be able to specify which lines that should be run (alternatively automatically get the equivalent of a "%-comment" on lines that should be discarded) without using any if-statements or similar that brings time overhead. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Have you profiled the code? Matlab has a pretty good profile built in. Add `profile on` before calling the stuff in the `.m` file and `profile viewer` at the end. You will probably see that those if statements will only take <0.02 seconds over the full run of the script. Regardless of iteration number.

Comment: Without looking at the code, one can adventure to say that you need to revise the design of your code. Most likely you need to split your script into functions.

Comment: @Kassym Dorsel - I have profiled the code. The lines take about the same time as an if-statement to execute, so adding an if-statement at each line would double the time it takes to run when all the 400 lines have to be executed.

Comment: @gire How would I do that?

Comment: @fixitinthemix it highly depends on your code. You can read some design patters/ideas [here](http://sourcemaking.com/).

Comment: "adding an if-statement at each line" why would you add `if` at each line? Use `if` to cover a large chunk of code. If that is not possible then it would mean that those 50 lines that you want to run are spread all over the .m file but then you spend more time commenting the remaining 350 out then you will spend on running the whole thing.

Comment: Besides even if you added `if` at each line this cannot be slower than running the line itself. The `if` statement would only evaluate a single logical variable which is either `true` or `false`. This is faster than anything else you are likely to have on those lines. Define a logical variable `skip` and set it to `false` at the beginning of the programme and add `if (~skip)` where needed. This should be pretty fast.

Comment: Consider posting a sample of this code.  This just sounds like a strange code design, and there is probably a way to write it so that it is easy to select, AND runs faster.

Comment: @PetrH That is my point, I did not want to add if-statements at each line but I could not cover large chunks with if-statements. The question was how I could manage this situation and I got two solid answers. Since that .m-file will be run A LOT of times it will not take more time to automatically comment lines that are not needed beforehand.

Comment: @fixitinthemix The key is **automatically**, what you were after was some kind of matlab preprocessor which I thought was not possible (google search revealed only poor solutions) - I am definitely glad to see such a thing is possible. I mainly questioned your statement *"The lines take about the same time as an if-statement to execute"* which is very very unlikely to be the case. Overall I agree with others who suggested a better programme design. Btw. if you require performance perhaps you should not be using matlab in the first place.

Comment: @PetrH But I am using matlab and I did require faster performance and I did not ask for a new programme design in my first post. But I am thankful that you took the time to look into the question. All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have lines that will be executed a lot of times, you may save some time by writing them into a separate function.

Here is how you could do it:

1. Create the function with all lines (called full.m)
2. Determine which lines you need, put this in a vector `v`
3. Import full.m as a cell array called `full`, (you can rightclick it and do the import, from here you can also create a script to automate this)
4. Write it to a file called reduced:

Writing can be done like so:

```
dlmwrite('reduced.m',vertcat(full{v}),'')
```

Comment: Note that if you need this, you may be using a rather awkward design, however that is hard to judge without seeing any code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
s = (1+1==2);

fin = fopen('foo.m','r');
fout = fopen('foo_edit.m','w+');
if s
    while (~feof(fin))
        tline = fgetl(fin);
        if (~isempty(regexp(tline, '^[^(% )].*\% conditional$', 'once')))
            fprintf(fout, '%% %s\n', tline);
        else
            fprintf(fout, '%s\n', tline);
        end
    end
else
    while (~feof(fin))
        tline = fgetl(fin);
        if (~isempty(regexp(tline, '^% .*\% conditional$', 'once')))
            fprintf(fout, '%s\n', tline(3:end));
        else
            fprintf(fout, '%s\n', tline);
        end
    end
end
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
delete foo.m
movefile('foo_edit.m', 'foo.m')
foo(5)
```

Just let Matlab make comments for you.

.... and this is `foo.m`

```
function y = foo (x)
x = x*5;
% x = x+1; % conditional
x = x+20;
% x = x*2; % conditional
y = x;
end
```

Comment: Yes it was basically exactly what I was looking for but the other answer was maybe a little cleaner so I accepted that.

Answer (score 0):

A `if`-statement is probably the fastest possibility, use it. You may alternatively read the file as a text file an run the parts you wish using `eval`. Without testing I am sure that the `if`-statement is faster or has the same speed, using `eval` often screws the JIT-Compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The lines take about the same time as an if-statement to execute, so adding an if-statement at each line would double the time it takes to run when all the 400 lines have to be executed.

Comment: Okay, then I got your question wrong. I thought you have some sections which are typically executed and you only have to add one or some if-statement, but not one for each line.